# Inside Haskell Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code that compiles and runs fine. I tried to make it more compact by replacing `case newEmployee of` with `case scanEmployee p of`, but it didn't work. There's probably an easy way to remove `newEmployee` (and `newTeam`) from the code right?

```
module Main( main ) where
import Control.Monad.State

data Employee  = EmployeeSW  Int Int | EmployeeHW Int String deriving ( Show )
data Employee' = EmployeeSW'     Int | EmployeeHW'    String deriving ( Show )

scanTeam :: [Employee] -> State (Int,Int) (Either String [Employee'])
scanTeam [    ] = return (Right [])
scanTeam (p:ps) = do
    newEmployee <- scanEmployee p
    case newEmployee of
        Left errorMsg -> return (Left errorMsg)
        Right e -> do
            newTeam <- scanTeam ps
            case newTeam of
                Right n -> return (Right (e:n))
                Left errorMsg -> return (Left errorMsg)

scanEmployee :: Employee -> State (Int,Int) (Either String Employee')
-- actual code for scanEmployee omitted ...
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but you might want to take a look at monad transformers, in particular `ExceptT`. It'd cut down the staircase of `case`s significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code a bit with `mapM` and `sequence`:

```
mapM scanEmployee :: [Employee] -> State (Int, Int) [Either String Employee')

sequence :: [ Either String a ] -> Either String [ a ]
```

(Note that these type signatures are simplifications and the actual types are more general. Specifically `mapM` and `sequence` work for any monad (not just `Either String`) and any traversable (not just `([])`))

And write a simple solution:

```
scanTeam = fmap sequence . mapM scanEmployee
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `LambdaCase` and be explicit with `>>=` instead of using `do` blocks. The result is not much shorter:

```
scanEmployee p >>= \case
    Left errorMsg -> return (Left errorMsg)
    Right e       -> do ...
```

Comment: I _very_ often do this as well.